# NSURLSession completion handler very slow

Tags: ios, swift2, nsurlsession, completionhandler

When I run the following code, I can print a response almost immediately, however, it can take ten seconds or more to appear in my view.  It seems like most similar problems are caused by the session and the handler being on different threads.  But why does it work eventually?  Very confused...

```
func downloadDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
   let url = NSURL(string: _detailsURL)!
   let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
   let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

      do {
         let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

             if let eyeColor = dict["eyeColor"] as? String {
                self._eyeColor = eyeColor
             }
          }
          catch {
             print("json error: \(error)")
          }
   }
   task.resume()
}
```

Comment: try google.com as url,maybe your server is slow.

Comment: I can usually print the response to Xcode's console in a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send your UI updates to the main queue, If you try to update it without sending it to the main queue it can take over a minute to update it.

```
func downloadDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
    let url = NSURL(string: _detailsURL)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

            if let eyeColor = dict["eyeColor"] as? String {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self._eyeColor = eyeColor
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("json error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amirn and Reshmi.  I actually had two problems - first I left out completed() and second, as you both said, I needed to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {}  I added the later to my updateUI function called in viewDidLoad and it's working great!

Answer (score 1):

**Use :**

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
{

/// to load your UI

}

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3 you can use this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
   self._eyeColor = eyeColor
}
```