# Lag when changing button visibility on JSON response

Tags: json, swift, uibutton

On successful JSON request, I wish to change the visibility of certain buttons that I have in my interface. However, when I do handle it in the manner as described below, I encounter tremendous lag for some reason. The print statement goes through in each of the state calls, but the visibility of the buttons themselves don't change for like even up to 30 seconds.

```
func buttonStateOne() {
    self.executeButton.isHidden = false
    self.clearButton.isHidden = false
    self.stopButton.isHidden = true
    self.greyExecuteButton.isHidden = true
    self.greyClearButton.isHidden = true
    self.greyStopButton.isHidden = false
    self.drawUIView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    print("On state one")
}

func buttonStateTwo() {
    self.executeButton.isHidden = true
    self.clearButton.isHidden = true
    self.stopButton.isHidden = true
    self.greyExecuteButton.isHidden = false
    self.greyClearButton.isHidden = false
    self.greyStopButton.isHidden = false
    self.drawUIView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    print("On state two")
}

func buttonStateThree() {
    self.executeButton.isHidden = true
    self.clearButton.isHidden = true
    self.stopButton.isHidden = false
    self.greyExecuteButton.isHidden = false
    self.greyClearButton.isHidden = false
    self.greyStopButton.isHidden = true
    self.drawUIView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    print("on state three")
}

@IBAction func sendLines() {
        self.buttonStateTwo()

        // Draw a path
        let theDrawView: DrawView = drawView as! DrawView
        var pathPoints = [Any]()
        for line in theDrawView.lines {
           pathPoints.append([line.start.x, line.start.y])
        }

        // Send the path
        let json: [String: Any] = [ "path": pathPoints ]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost:5000/path")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
                return
            }
            var responseString: String = ""
            let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: String] {
                print(responseJSON["status"]!)
                responseString = responseJSON["status"]!
            }
            if responseString == "SUCCESS" {
                self.buttonStateThree()
            } else {
                self.buttonStateOne()
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLSession completion handler very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029692/nsurlsession-completion-handler-very-slow)

Answer (score 1):

The UI must be updated on the main thread so dispatch the block including the `buttonState...` methods to the main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   if responseString == "SUCCESS" {
       self.buttonStateThree()
   } else {
       self.buttonStateOne()
   }
}
```